# Exclude related records - guilt by association

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this MySQL query:

```
select * 
from Movies_Genres 
where MovieID = 271
```

That returns the following recordset:

```
ID    MovieID  GenreID
======================
924   271      8
1251  271      13
```

`Movies_Genres` is a union/junction table with `many-many` relationships.

Now if I run this slightly modified query:

```
select * 
from Movies_Genres 
where MovieID = 271
and GenreID <> 13
```

I get the following recordset:

```
ID    MovieID  GenreID
======================
924   271      8
```

So far so good. But what I'm trying to achieve is to have 0 records returned for that 2nd query if the movie has a related `GenreID` of `13`. So, the fact that in my query above the movie has related genres of 13 AND 8, I want 0 records returned because the movie has a GenreID of 13. If it had a GenreID of, say, 8, 1, and 2 - then I would want 3 records returned. If it had a GenreID of only 13, I would want 0 records returned -- which it already does correctly. To summarize: *Any movie with a related GenreID of 13 should never return any records, even if it also has other linked GenreIDs*.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the original records, then `not exists` seems appropriate:

```
select mg.* 
from Movies_Genres mg
where not exists (select 1
                  from movies_genres mg2
                  where mg2.MovieID = mg.MovieID and 
                        mg2.GenreID = 13
                 );
```

If you just want the movies rather than the `genreID` details, you can use `group by`:

```
select mg.MovieID
from Movies_Genres mg
group by mg.MovieID
having sum( mg2.GenreID = 13 ) = 0;
```

In fact, you can add the genre ids as a list in this case:

```
select mg.MovieID, group_concat(mg.GenreID) as genreids
from Movies_Genres mg
group by mg.MovieID
having sum( mg2.GenreID = 13 ) = 0;
```

Comment: `having sum( mg2.GenreID = 13 )` will assigning genreId to 13 work even i tried the same way similar to what count(..)

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja . . . Huh?  I really don't understand your comment.  The expression `sum( mg.GenreID = 13 ) ` counts the number of times that `genreId` is 13.  The `= 0` says there are no such rows for the movie.

Comment: thats what i said the thing is this a correct way of making aggregation work to avoid writing the same column in group by

Comment: This seems really promising but I cannot add my order by: `ORDER BY RAND()` - it throws an error on the `order by`

Comment: @HerrimanCoder . . . Why can't you add `order by rand()`?  That should go right after the `having` clause.

Comment: PEBKAC - I had a stray semicolon. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

One option involves aggregation:

```
SELECT MovieID
FROM Movies_Genres
WHERE MovieID = 271
GROUP BY MovieID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN GenreID = 13 THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

The above query is somewhat trivial, because it would at most return a single `MovieID`, `271`, if it did not have the 13 genre associated with it.  If you want to find the full records, we can try:

```
SELECT mg.*
FROM Movies_Genres mg
WHERE mg.MovieID NOT IN (SELECT MovieID FROM Movies_Genres GROUP BY MovieID
                         HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN GenreID = 13 THEN 1 END) > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need a group by with having

```
        select * 
          from Movies_Genres 
          group by MovieId having count(GenreID=13) =0
```